# parallel assignment variable from python to java (Pi algorithm)

Tags: java, python, algorithm, variable-assignment, pi

I would like to translate a python algorithm to Java, I have this source code (using parallel asignment variable (doesn't exist in Java :( )

```py
# -*- coding: cp1252 -*-
#! /usr/bin/env python

import sys



def main():
    k, a, b, a1, b1 = 2L, 4L, 1L, 12L, 4L
    while 1:
        p, q, k = k*k, 2L*k+1L, k+1L
        a, b, a1, b1 = a1, b1, p*a+q*a1, p*b+q*b1
        d, d1 = a/b, a1/b1
        while d == d1:
            output(d)
            a, a1 = 10L*(a%b), 10L*(a1%b1)
            d, d1 = a/b, a1/b1

def output(d):
    sys.stdout.write(`int(d)`)
    sys.stdout.flush()
    #ecriture en continue du chiffre
    pi = open("flypi.html", "a")
    pi.write(`int(d)`)
    pi.write("\n")
    pi.close()


main()
```

So, first I recoded the same script without parallel assignement variable :

```py
# -*- coding: cp1252 -*-
#! /usr/bin/env python

import sys



def main():
    #k, a, b, a1, b1 = 2L, 4L, 1L, 12L, 4L
    k = 2L
    a = 4L
    b = 1L
    a1 = 12L
    b1 = 4L

    while 1:

        #p, q, k = k*k, 2L*k+1L, k+1L
        kk = k
        p = kk*kk
        q = 2L*kk+1L
        k = kk+1L

        #a, b, a1, b1 = a1, b1, p*a+q*a1, p*b+q*b1
        aa = a
        bb = b
        a = a1
        b = b1
        a1 = p*aa+q*a1
        b1 = p*bb+q*b1

        #d, d1 = a/b, a1/b1
        d = a/b
        d1 = a1/b1
        while d == d1:
            output(d)

            #a, a1 = 10L*(a%b), 10L*(a1%b1)
            a = 10L*(a%b)
            a1 = 10L*(a1%b1)

            #d, d1 = a/b, a1/b1
            d = a/b
            d1 = a1/b1

def output(d):
    sys.stdout.write(`int(d)`)
    sys.stdout.flush()
    #ecriture en continue du chiffre
    pi = open("flypi.html", "a")
    pi.write(`int(d)`)
    pi.write("\n")
    pi.close()


main()
```

The output of these two script is the same:

```
31415926535897932384626433832795028841971693993751058209749445923078164062862089 (crt+c)
```

Now here is the script I made in Java (almost the same as the second python script):

```
public static void cal(){
    //int i = 0;
    long d = 0;
    long k = 2L;
    long a = 4L;
    long b = 1L, a1 = 12L, b1 = 4L;
    long p = 0, q = 0, d1 = 0;

    long aa = 0, bb = 0;
    long kk = 0;


    while(true){

        kk = k;
        p = kk*kk;
        q = 2L*kk+1L;
        k = kk+1L;

        aa = a;
        bb = b;
        a = a1;
        b = b1;
        a1 = p*aa+q*a1;
        b1 = p*bb+q*b1;

        d = a/b;
        d1 = a1/b1;
        while(d == d1){
            System.out.print(d);
            try {
                Thread.sleep(100);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            a = 10L*(a%b);
            a1 = 10L*(a1%b1);

            d = a/b;
            d1 = a1/b1;
        }
        //i++;

    }
}
```

but the output is wrong :

```
31415926530000000001-100000000000000000100-300000101000000000000000000000000000000000000 (ctr+c)
```

Thank you, and sorry for the long post :)

EDIT:
So yes it's a buffer overflow.
I tried to implement BigInteger and it works fine !! thank you !

Comment: The presence of `-` in the output suggests that some numbers are going negative due to overflow.  Can integers in your Python program be indefinitely large?  (I don't know Python.)  `long` values in Java have a limit of 2^63-1, and if a computation goes over that limit, it will wrap around and may produce a negative value.  I'm not saying that's the problem; it's just my first guess.

Comment: Specifically, if `b` gets larger than 2^63/10, then `a%b` could produce a result that is larger than 2^63/10, which means that `a = 10L*(a%b)` will cause `a` to go negative.  If this seems to be the problem, look into using `BigInteger` instead of `long`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python integers can be arbitrarily large. In Java a long consists of 64 bits and can therefore only store numbers smaller than about 2**64 / 2.

If a number is too big, the first bits of it are discarded and the most significant bit that is not overwrites the sign of the integer, resulting in negative numbers in mathematically impossible places.

Use BigInteger as ajb suggests or change your calculations in some way.